# Favicon does not show up when doing window.open() in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In Google Chrome, when I create a new tab using the JavaScript function `window.open()`, and then add a favicon, the new tab created does not display the favicon.

Here is a code sample that reproduces the error:

```
var w = window.open();
var link = w.document.createElement('link');
link.id = 'fav';
link.rel = 'icon';
link.type = 'image/x-icon';
link.href = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico';
w.document.head.appendChild(link);
```

The favicon is displayed in Firefox but not in Chrome (tested with Chrome 58).

(To test the sample code, authorize the browser to open new popups)

How can I make it work? Is it the expected Chrome behavior or a bug?

Comment: I am having a similar issue, I am opening a window where I am placing data from an Ajax post as content and even if I change the Icon link to a base64 i.e. not linking to a hosted Ico it fails to show